# How to use variables inside autocmd?

Tags: autocmd

I have defined the following augroup:

```
    vim9script
    augroup MY_AUGROUP
        autocmd!
        autocmd CursorMoved,CursorHold <buffer>
            \ if index(b:line_numbers, line('.')) != -1
            \ | echo b:messages[index(b:line_numbers, line('.'))]
            \ | else
            \ | echo ""
            \ | endif
    augroup END
```

and it works fine, but I wish define a variable `idx` to avoid carrying the verbose `index(b:line_numbers, line('.'))`

So, I tried the following

```
    vim9script
    var idx = -1
    augroup MY_AUGROUP
        autocmd!
        autocmd CursorMoved,CursorHold <buffer>
            \ idx = index(b:line_numbers, line('.'))
            \ | if idx != -1
            \ | echo b:error_messages[idx]
            \ | else
            \ | echo ""
            \ | endif
    augroup END
```

But I get the error `Not an editor command`.
I also tried the following:

```
    augroup MY_AUGROUP
        autocmd!
        autocmd CursorMoved,CursorHold <buffer>
            \ var idx = index(b:line_numbers, line('.'))
            \ | if idx != -1
            \ | echo b:error_messages[idx]
            \ | else
            \ | echo ""
            \ | endif
    augroup END
```

and I get the error `redefining script item: "idx"`.

How can I fix this problem?
But more in general: how variables shall be used in autocmd?

Comment: "But more in general: how variables shall be used in autocmd?" Like anywhere. Autocommands are not special. Your way of cramming so much logic in an autocommand, on the other hand, *that* is quite special.

Comment: It's just a if else logic, that echo two different things, I don't think it's a too much logic. But thinking a bit on it, moving that in a function and just call that function in the autocomand may solve my problem... hum... I should try it.

Comment: ... in-fact it works. I know why the latter snippet it didn't work but I am not sure why the second last didn't work. Perhaps because of the scope of `idx`?

Comment: yes, try using explicit global scope for your variable `g:idx`

Comment: You can try the braces {} for vim9script. Anyone have the help reference handy? Anyway, your attempts failed because the RHS is not vim9script by default, II(U/R)C

Comment: @D.BenKnoble Auch! Good points! Yeah, I forgot the braces actually, but I think a function call is much easier to maintain and to read! :D I like the braces idea though.